# Max() Behavior Different Between MS Access and SQL server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, aggregate-functions, ms-access-2003

So I am in the process of rewriting an MS Access application to a SQL server backend. I am struggling with some unusual behavior in the way Access is using `MAX()` and how SQL Server is doing it.  Maybe it is lack of sleep but I have been staring at this for hours and I can't figure out why the SQL server results are different.

Sample Data:

```
Acct        ByUser  TranType    TranID      AddID   ClearTime               TranTime
12345678    CZ12           W    55545124    CZ36    12/12/2011 9:45:31 AM   12/12/2011 9:45:31 AM
12345678    CZ24           W    55545124    CZ36    12/12/2011 10:01:26 AM  12/12/2011 10:01:26 AM
12345678    CZ36           W    55545124    CZ36    12/12/2011 9:45:31 AM   12/12/2011 9:45:31 AM
12345678    MG12           W    55545124    CZ36    12/12/2011 10:48:43 AM  12/12/2011 10:48:43 AM
12345678    CZ25           W    55545124    CZ36    12/12/2011 9:45:31 AM   12/12/2011 9:45:31 AM
```

MS Access query:

```
SELECT Acct, TypeID, TranType
    , Max(TranTime) AS MaxOfTranTime
    , AddID
    , Max(ClearTime) AS MaxOfClearTime
FROM Cleared 
WHERE 
(
    ((ByUser) Like "CZ*" Or (ByUser) Like "TR*" Or 
    (ByUser) Like "RR*" Or (ByUser) Like "MG*" Or 
    (ByUser) Like "RN*" Or (ByUser) Like "PS*" Or 
    (ByUser) Like "OP*" Or (ByUser) Like "JA*" Or 
    (ByUser) Like "IC*" Or (ByUser) Like "IB*" Or 
    (ByUser) Like "FO*" Or (ByUser) Like "DV*" Or 
    (ByUser) Like "CD*" Or (ByUser) Like "BO*" Or 
    (ByUser) Like "2D*")
)
GROUP BY Acct, TypeID, TranType, AddID
```

Results in Access:

```
Account     TranID    TranType  MaxOfTranTime               AddID   MaxOfClearTime
12345678    55545124    W       12/12/2011  10:48:43 AM      CZ36   12/12/2011 9:45:31 AM
```

The query in SQL server is slightly different in that my ByUsers are stored in a table to minimize typing in tons of queries.

```
SELECT C.Acct
    , C.RequestId
    , C.TypeCode
    , Max(C.TranTime) as MaxTranTime
    , C.AddUserId
    , Max(C.ClearDate) As MaxClearDate
FROM Cleared C
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM UserIdFilter U
                WHERE ByUserId LIKE U.UserId) 
GROUP BY Acct, RequestId, TypeCode, AddUserId
```

The SQL Server results are:

```
Account     TranID    TranType  MaxOfTranTime          AddID    MaxOfClearTime
12345678    55545124    W      12/12/2011  10:48:43 AM  CZ36    12/12/2011  10:48:43 AM
```

When I go through this it seems to me that SQL server is correct in getting the MaxOfClearTime of 12/12/2011  10:48:43 AM but am I missing something?  Does Access process `MAX()` differently?  I feel like I am losing my mind with this so any other eyes on this would be great.

Comment: Seems that on the 1st you use 'Max(ClearTime) AS MaxOfClearTime' and on the 2nd you use 'Max(C.ClearDate) As MaxReasClearDate'

Comment: @ysrb they are the same I just copied it over wrong, the queries, data need to be scrubbed before posting to any site.  I corrected it

Comment: Does running "SELECT * 
                FROM UserIdFilter U 
                WHERE ByUserId LIKE U.UserId" give you the same values as in the first query??

Comment: @MitchWheat yes, I get the same values in the first query. Exact same record count, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put the data you provided in Access and ran the query, and it provided the output I'd expect i.e. `10 > 9`.

Of course I did assume that both ClearTime and TranTime are being stored as DateTime, If I change them to Text and alter the formatting to match your sample then I get the same results as you i.e. `"9" > "10"`.

Could you check the schema of the table in MS Access?

Comment: this pointed me in the right direction. it was a text field in access and not a date field.